# Trouble loading Firebug Lite in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-domain, firebug, firebug-lite

I have downloaded the latest firebug-lite and placed it in my local directory and I am including it `<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/firebug-lite.js"></script>` just like that. IE is throwing this error in the console - `SCRIPT5: Access is denied.`

It seems like it's a cross-domain issue for IE, which I am not sure how it is - I do want to try to get it working in this specific way(local file) - the other ways to include it do work somewhat.

Comment: Why are you using firebug lite? IE8+ has a debugger and they can run as IE7.

Comment: Are you running this off a web server or the local file system?  I don't think IE will, by default, run script off local files..

Comment: I got tired of IE's developer tools. All the files are on a local virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the error Access is denied. is concerned, It is obvious that you are trying to run a script for which you don't have privileges. Are you the administrator of this PC, Are you using the limited or guest account while browsing using IE.

Nontheless, you can always follow these steps by Colin Pickard to get it working in IE

1. Go to some Firebug Lite page (http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite).
2. Click the "add to Favorites Bar" button on the Favorites Bar.
3. This will give you a bookmark to http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite.
4. Right click on the "Firebug Lite" link and choose "Copy Shortcut".
5. Right click on your new bookmark and choose Properties.
6. Paste the bookmarklet into the URL box and close.

Comment: Well I am using an administrator account, the script runs fine when I include it via `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js"></script>`, but it's slow - thus I wanted to include it from a local directory. I did try the bookmark trick before that and it's the same deal - slowish. The bookmark way was not very stable - it seemed to work sometimes, but mostly it just didn't open.

Comment: I too had that problem, I guess this is obvious as the script needs some time to load from your local directory.

Comment: Well, not just the loading, even when trying to use it, it would hesitate.

Comment: Then you should use inbuilt debugger for IE, called IE developer tools bar.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got any of the ["ie7.js"](https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) shims loaded, too? I tried using "ie9.js" (a later version for IE8) and it screwed with Firebug Lite for me. I feel your pain; Firebug Lite is a damn sight better than the IE8's absolutely useless native tools.

Comment: I only had the [console-shim.js](https://github.com/kayahr/console-shim/blob/master/console-shim.js) loaded, but I don't think that's it. FirebugLite just works too slowly for my tastes, so I just stuck to IE's developer tools, which yeah, are very much obsolete at this point - comparing them to Chrome's dev tools. So no solution yet, sorry.